# Does Vaadin Combobox setValue method fire a ValueChangeEvent?

Tags: combobox, vaadin

I'm trying to find a way to set default value to combobox. I have to run a method if a value changes in combobox but not when I set default value.

Comment: Yes, it does. From the wording, it seems like you already tried something. Why don't you show us your code and explain what's the problem with it?

Comment: @defaultlocale Thanks for the comment. I solved it. I set the event handlers after I set the default value. It worked for me.

Comment: So, can you post your own answer, so someone else can see it and use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the event handlers after setting the default value.

```
  ComboBox b = new ComboBox();

  b.addItem(1);

  b.select(1);

  b.addValueChangeListener(event -> someMethod());
```

you can also remove the event handler and then set the value then set the value change listener again.

```
ComboBox b = new ComboBox();

b.addItem(1);

ValueChangeListener vcl = new 
ValueChangeListener()
{
  @Override
  public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event)
  {
     System.out.println("value changed");
  }
};
b.addValueChangeListener(vcl);
b.removeValueChangeListener(vcl);
b.select(1);
b.addValueChangeListener(vcl);
```

Comment: This is no longer possible as of Vaadin 8